# NodeJS passport-ldapauth always returns 'Invalid Username/Password'

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm currently working on a project in which I'm trying to authenticate users against the school's LDAP Server. For this purpose, I'm trying to use the NPM Package `passport-ldapauth`.

To be said in advance: I'm to 100% sure that the provided `username` and `password` are registered and valid on the LDAP Server.

Below is the code that I'm trying to use at the moment to authenticate against the local LDAP Server in my NodeJS application:

```
var LDAPStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
 done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
 done(null, id);
});

passport.use('ldap', new LDAPStrategy({
 usernameField: 'username',
 passwordField: 'password',
  server: {
   url: 'ldap://server-ip-address:389',
   bindDN: 'cn=read-only-user,dc=foo,dc=bar',
   bindCredentials: 'read-only-user-pw',
   searchBase: 'dc=foo,dc=bar',
   searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={{username}})'
 }
}));
```

So far I tried many different options for the `bindDN` as well as `searchBase`. I also have the full bindDN which looks something like this:

`bindDN: CN=read-only-user,OU=LDAP,OU=AdFoo,OU=Userfoo,OU=FOO,DC=foo,DC=bar`

and a `searchBase` like this:

`searchBase: 'ou=Foobar,ou=Anotherfoobar,ou=FOO,dc=foo,dc=bar'`

though nothing seems to work, unfortunately. 
I already checked whether or not these parameters (`username, password`) are given in the request's body, and they are.

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
 // Prints the values that the frontend passes in the request body
 console.log(req.body.username); 
 console.log(req.body.password);
 next();
});

router.post('/', bodyParseArray, passport.authenticate('ldap', (err, user, info) => {
 console.log('Error: ', err); // prints: null
 console.log('User: ', user); // prints: false
 console.log('Info: ', info); // prints: { message: 'Invalid username/password' }
}));
```

---

I tried doing a `ldapsearch` using the terminal also. This `ldapsearch` for me looks as follows:

```
MBP-Stoger:~ Stephan$ ldapsearch -H ldap://server-ip-address:389 
-D cn=read-only-user,ou=LDAP,ou=AdFoo,ou=Userfoo,ou=FOO,dc=foo,dc=bar
-w read-only-user-pw -b ou=Foobar,ou=Anotherfoobar,ou=FOO,dc=foo,dc=bar 
"sAMAccountName=example.user"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=Foobar,ou=Anotherfoobar,ou=FOO,dc=foo,dc=bar> with scope subtree
# filter: sAMAccountName=example.user
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 1
```

As far as I can tell, it seems like `ldapsearch` returns the expected result, yet the NodeJS Module seems to have some issue with whatever input it is receiving. As last I thought that maybe the `username/password` values weren't passed into the module, though doing `console.log()` for both in the module's `.prototype.authenticate` function shows that the values are correctly being passed into the module itself, therefore I guess the issue has to lie somewhere in my configuartion, though I don't understand the module and package itself well enough to figure out the problem myself.

Anyone out there who might be able to help me figuring out why my NodeJS Application fails authenticating the user successfully?

---

Lastly, some spec information, if that's necessary:

```
OS: MacOSX HighSierra (10.13.3)
Node: v8.6.0
passport: v0.4.0
passport-ldapauth: v2.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same issue and problem was with organizational unit (OU). You need to mention ou in bindDN, ou=Users and also if read-only-user is part of another ou we need to mention that also. So this code need to work for you.

```
server: {
   url: 'ldap://server-ip-address:389',
   bindDN: 'cn=read-only-user,ou=Users,ou=user-other-ou,dc=foo,dc=bar',
   bindCredentials: 'read-only-user-pw',
   searchBase: 'dc=foo,dc=bar',
   searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={{username}})'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the bindDn in this format for it to work smoothly:

```
bindDN: [domain]\\[username]
```